# PHP Missing Function In Older Version

Tags: php

My this PHP function converts a datetime string into more readable way to represent passed date and time. This is working perfect in PHP version 5.3.0 but on the server side it is PHP version 5.2.17 which lacks this function. Is there a way I can fix this efficiently? This is not only a function which needs this "diff" function but there are many more.

```
public function ago($dt1)
 {
  $interval = date_create('now')->diff(date_create($dt1));
  $suffix = ($interval->invert ? ' ago' : '-');
  if ($v = $interval->y >= 1) return $this->pluralize($interval->y, 'year') . $suffix;
  if ($v = $interval->m >= 1) return $this->pluralize($interval->m, 'month') . $suffix;
  if ($v = $interval->d >= 1) return $this->pluralize($interval->d, 'day') . $suffix;
  if ($v = $interval->h >= 1) return $this->pluralize($interval->h, 'hour') . $suffix;
  if ($v = $interval->i >= 1) return $this->pluralize($interval->i, 'minute') . $suffix;
   return $this->pluralize($interval->s, 'second') . $suffix;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to this re-written function which works pretty well.

```
class DateTimeFormatter
{
    private $now;
    public $invert;
    public $y, $m, $d, $h, $i, $s;

    function DateTimeFormatter()
    {
        $this->now = date_parse(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));   
    }

    function now()
    {
        $this->now = date_parse(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        return $this->now;
    }

    function diff($dt)
    {
        if (!is_array($dt))
            $dt = date_parse($dt);

        if ($this->now() > $dt)
        {
            $this->invert = 1;
            $this->y = $this->now['year'] - $dt['year'];
            $this->m = $this->now['month'] - $dt['month'];
            $this->d = $this->now['day'] - $dt['day'];
            $this->h = $this->now['hour'] - $dt['hour'];
            $this->i = $this->now['minute'] - $dt['minute'];
            $this->s = $this->now['second'] - $dt['second'];
        }
        else
        {
            $this->invert = 0;
            $this->y = $dt['year'] - $this->now['year'];
            $this->m = $dt['month'] - $this->now['month'];
            $this->d = $dt['day'] - $this->now['day'];
            $this->h = $dt['hour'] - $this->now['hour'];
            $this->i = $dt['minute'] - $this->now['minute'];
            $this->s = $dt['second'] - $this->now['second'];
        }

        return $this;                            
    }

    function ago($datetime)
    {
        $interval = $this->diff($datetime);
        $suffix = ($interval->invert ? ' ago' : '');
        if ($v = $interval->y >= 1) return $this->pluralize($interval->y, 'year') . $suffix;
        if ($v = $interval->m >= 1) return $this->pluralize($interval->m, 'month') . $suffix;
        if ($v = $interval->d >= 1) return $this->pluralize($interval->d, 'day') . $suffix;
        if ($v = $interval->h >= 1) return $this->pluralize($interval->h, 'hour') . $suffix;
        if ($v = $interval->i >= 1) return $this->pluralize($interval->i, 'minute') . $suffix;
        return $this->pluralize($interval->s, 'second') . $suffix;
    }

    function pluralize( $count, $text )
    {
        return $count . (($count == 1) ? (" $text") : (" ${text}s"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be found in the comment right below the one you found your code in on php.net:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
<?php
function date_diff($date1, $date2) {
    $current = $date1;
    $datetime2 = date_create($date2);
    $count = 0;
    while(date_create($current) < $datetime2){
        $current = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($current)));
        $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}

echo (date_diff('2010-3-9', '2011-4-10')." days <br \>");
?>
```

Comment: and you can add it to your application with `if(!function_exists('date_diff')) { // declare function here }` so you wont have to bother which version is on the server.

Comment: but I specifically need the function "diff"

Comment: @Umair See the manual. `date_diff` is the procedural alias of `Date::diff`

Comment: @Gordon: the function will always output difference of days

Comment: @Umair ah ok, now I see what you mean. Sorry. So you are not only after `DateTime::diff` but also after `DateInterval`. See if this one helps: http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-16.html. You should change the method given there to return an object instead of an array.

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks for your efforts. I thought I should write that function myself and I did it. I am answering my own question now.